# How to set media type with Python requests?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to reproduce this curl statement with Python requests:

`curl -T data/Graph.obj -X POST localhost:8080`

My Python code is the following:

```
files = {'Graph.obj': open('data/Graph.obj', 'rb')}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080', files=files)
```

The curl statement works fine. But for the Python code I get the error `HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type HTTP`.

How do I set the media type properly? Or what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file